# Work around for -webkit-overflow-scrolling offset bug

Tags: ios, css, safari, webkit

The bug is described in detail here https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134596

Relevant part is this:

> Without Scrolling you should be able to click any of the radio buttons
>
> Now scroll down the page
>
> Trying to click any of the radio buttons on the left results in an
>   offset click. One of the radio buttons below your click will receive
>   the event.
>
> Expected: The radio button I clicked on gets focus
>
> Actual: The click event is offset the amount the iframe was scrolled.

Main difference is im not using an iframe, just a div, but the same problem.

If I remove either `overflow:auto` (but it wont let me scroll then) or `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property the correct clicks happen. It looks like it was fixed in a nightly, but this has to work now and for backwards compatibility. Is there a hack to get this to work? My best idea so far is to just not have that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` prop for iOS until it works, but that kinda sucks because momentum scrolling is what makes it feel much more like an app.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle, CodePen, or live demo of your bug, with a minimized code sample.